# Duplicate rows in GridView with SQL join query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, gridview

I have a GridView in my application, where I am supposed to show list of records by joining different tables. The SQL Join query shows records but say within 1000 rows it shows 2 to 3 records twice. Is it because of the sql query?

The SQL Query I am using is:

```
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select dt.name, rg.sex, ad.dt_adm, st.*  " + 
      "from stdn_st st, stdn_reg rg, stdn_det dt, admsn_det ad where st.college='" + 
      lbl_college.Text + "' and st.course='" + lbl_course.Text + "' and st.sem='" + 
      lbl_sem.Text + "' and st.pass='" + lbl_pass.Text + "' and rg.id=st.sid and " + 
      "dt.sid=st.sid and ad.sid=st.sid", con);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `distinct`? also try to use the `JOIN` syntax instead of the old one like: `select distinct
  dt.name, 
  rg.sex, 
  ad.dt_adm, 
  st.*  
from stdn_st st
inner join stdn_reg rg on rg.id=st.sid
inner join stdn_det dt on dt.sid=st.sid
inner join admsn_det ad on ad.sid=st.sid
where st.college='" + lbl_college.Text + "' and st.course='" + lbl_course.Text + "' and st.sem='" + lbl_sem.Text + "' and st.pass='" + lbl_pass.Text + "'`

Comment: @PeterRing All the table contains only unique records.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Would you mind to help me at Join. I find join a bit confusing

Comment: @umesh-sinha but you write in your qustion: "...it shows 2 to 3 records twice" then what do you mean by that?

Comment: Say there are 1000 records with sl number 1 to 1000 and when I generate the grid somewhere within 1000 records say sl number 55 and 744 repeated itself for twice or thrice. Where as in the DB there is no such duplicate records.

Comment: The `JOIN` syntax you are using in your query is the old join syntax, which by listing the tables with `,` in the from clause and put the conditions in the `WHERE` clause, the other syntax is by using the `JOIN` keyword and put the condition on the `ON`, See [**this article for more details**](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: Have you tried `DISTINCT`?

Comment: You should also **[use parameterised queries](http://bobby-tables.com/)**

Comment: GarethD is right, your code could be attacked with SQL injection here pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

Use latest syntax of join. As per your requirement you can use any of these.

1. INNER JOIN
2. LEFT JOIN
3. RIGHT JOIN
4. OUTER JOIN

Comment: I am not sure how this answer the question? As far as I can see, the OP missing the `distinct` !!